# Generate jar with Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring-boot

I'm trying to develop an application with spring boot that generates an executable jar. And use database connections and use external properties Is this possible?

Comment: yes, it is possible. Please google for a tutorial

Answer (score 1):

This link will be helpful. It depends on what build tool you are using.
https://spring.io/guides/gs/spring-boot/#scratch

For configurable properties , refer to application.properties file in spring boot.
https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/common-application-properties.html

Comment: Thank Dinesh. The structure of my app is fine. Maybe i don't understand many components of Spring Boot.

Comment: What application are you trying to build? What are the build tool you are using? The package structure also plays an important role in spring boot app.

Answer (score 0):

Start with Spring Initializr.  I'd recommend using Gradle for your build.

https://start.spring.io/

Add JPA as a dependency.  After downloading the project, add properties to the src/main/resources/application.properties file.  Look at the following link for "spring.datasource" specific properties to configure your Database connection.

Running the following command will create an executable Jar in the build/libs folder.

```
./gradlew build
```

I'll need more information about your full intent if you want to "externalize" your properties.  You can start here:

https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html

Comment: I'm working with maven. Why is recommend use gradle?

Comment: @SpringDeveloper Gradle does everything that Maven does, and more.  However, go with what you know.  Gradle has a pretty steep learning curve, and Maven will do what you need.